# Database duplicate name check numrows always comes back as 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a function to check my DB for duplicate names before entry. I have tried about three different ways to capture the numrows of duplicate entries but numrows always comes back as zero. My most recent code is below.

So I have now tried this but still numrows is zero and there is about ten of the same entry in there now so definitely shouldn't be zero.

```
function check_item_name($item_id, $name) {

    global $DBConnect;
    
$get_name =  $DBConnect->stmt_init();
$query = "SELECT count(1)
          FROM item_id 
          WHERE item_id = ? AND name = ? AND end_date IS NULL ";
$get_name->prepare($query);
$get_name->bind_param("is", $item_id, $name);
$get_name->execute();
$get_name->bind_result($name);
$get_name->fetch();
if ($name){
    $success = 1;
} else {
    $success = 0;
}
var_error_log("------success-------------");
var_error_log($success);

return $success;
}
```

Comment: With this particular code the problem is that you cannot use bind_result and store_result ant the same time. Besides there are other problems. Check the proper way here: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value

Comment: Thanks ill try it now :)

Comment: Sorry bud it didnt work still reurning 0 :(

Comment: if it's really 0, not null, then it's your query. 0 means there is no such data in your table you are looking for. Note than there is no such data in reality, as opposite to what you *think* there is. There could be a huge difference.

Comment: I think i may have solved it with your original link but let me check and ill come back to you soon but thankyou for your help eitherway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many apologies the below code works perfectly i just needed to adjust my ajax call for it. thankyou to YourCommonSense for the answer.

```
function check_item_name($item_id, $name) {

global $DBConnect;

$get_name =  $DBConnect->stmt_init();
$query = "SELECT count(1)
      FROM item_id 
      WHERE item_id = ? AND name = ? AND end_date IS NULL ";
$get_name->prepare($query);
$get_name->bind_param("is", $item_id, $name);
$get_name->execute();
$get_name->bind_result($name);
$get_name->fetch();
 if ($name){
     $success = 1;
} else {
     $success = 0;
}

return $success;
}
```